# Search pattern as variable in a csv file with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, pattern-matching

I've a csv file with urls to test. Each url has a pattern which we have to test.

How can I build this in my jmx file?

It's a variable but how jmeter can understand that it's a variable?

Thank you for your help.

example: I would like to test on the site "wwww.amazon.com" if the pattern "my account" exist.

Comment: What does it mean to "test" url? Could you provide more information and possibly some example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have CSV file with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of `${variable_name_here}` and want JMeter to resolve them in the runtime - you need to wrap the variable reference into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

```
${__eval(${myVar})}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)